# Do any Alchemist class features require Craft checks?

Tags: skills, pathfinder-2e

Advanced Alchemy and Quick Alchemy explicitly do *not* require Craft checks.

Chirurgeons *could* use Craft instead of Medicine, but they need to advance the latter for the many useful skill feats.

So it seems Champions and Warpriests<sup>1</sup> need Craft more than Alchemists do. Is this correct?

---

1. to fix shields ruined by Shield Block

Comment: What is the point of the final line? You had a perfectly fine question until you brought in two unrelated classes.

Comment: @lfusaso I wanted to show the contrast

Comment: I would reword your last question to something like your title, instead of asking "Is this correct?", since as written you sort of have two questions ("do Alchemists need craft" and "do Champions/Warpriests need it more").

Comment: Note that with the latest errata and clarification, [Chirurgeon alchemists can use Crafting to qualify for Medicine skill feats](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq). Doesn't invalidate the question, but does make Crafting of more apparent use for Chirurgeons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the basic ability to craft alchemical items granted to you by the Alchemy class feature (via granting you the Alchemical Crafting feat), several Alchemist Feats make use of the Crafting skill, although they seem to mostly modify how the basic uses of Crafting work rather than grant new abilities that rely on your skill.

Feats that directly interact with the Crafting skill:

Alchemical Savant makes identifying alchemical items using Crafting easier, faster, and safer:

- Efficient Alchemy doubles the speed you can create alchemical items
- Improbable Elixirs allows you to Craft a number of potions as though they were elixirs, substituting your alchemical reagents and alchemist's tools for the magical components and other required tool kits normally required to brew that potion
- Craft Philosopher's Stone allows you to create a philosopher's stone;  while doing so doesn't require Crafting directly, getting either benefit from the stone (making an elixir of rejuvenation or creating precious metals) requires you to be a legendary Crafter, and the creating precious metals option requires you to make successful Crafting rolls (and gives 50% more gp for critical successes).

Feats that indirectly benefit from the Crafting skill:
Feats like Potent Poisoner, Extend Elixir, and Perfect Mutagen apply to poisons, elixirs, and mutagens you create, whether using Crafting or your Advanced or Quick Alchemy class features. (Many of these only apply if you are the creator and also the user, but several - particularly poison-affecting feats - apply to all the ones you create.)

Remember that things created with Advanced Alchemy only last a day, while the things you've stockpiled using Crafting in downtime are permanent until consumed.  So creating spare bombs or elixirs ahead of time will help in the case of a busy day that runs you out of your infused options.